# Mac as wi-fi hotspot: how many devices can connect?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, wifi

Is there a theoretical or practical limit to the number of devices that can be connected to a Macbook Pro sharing its internet connection as a wi-fi hotspot?

Answer (score 2):

On OSX Yosemite (beta 10.10.3), on MacBook Pro (13-inch, Mid 2012), today (2015-04-28), I've connected 15 different devices (Android, iOS, Win, OSX) via WiFi hotspot (sharing internet via Ethernet), and reported very low decline in internet bandwith with each new device connected.

Answer (score 1):

It can connect at max 7 devices, I have tried to connect more but wasn't able to.

Comment: At least as of today, May 15, 2014 and OS X Mavericks I have connected around 15 Android tablets to my MBP. Personally, I don't know what the limit is.

Comment: My data was based on the MBP Early 2011 model.

Answer (score 1):

I regularly try connecting 27 Wi-Fi modules (ESP-12F) and find that typically around three or four don't connect. It's slightly different every time, so the limit is probably 24.

In my case I'm using a Mac Mini 2009 model to share the internet.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about limit but I'm using 5 devices (3 mobiles and 1 macbook air and 1 windows 8 laptop) without any issue. data transfer ratio is also good.